# Opening a video from a menu item into an iframe on the same page

Tags: html, css, iframe, video

I have a menu with multiple links to videos that play through my company's internal video player. The videos are stored in amazon cloud service. Currently the videos href is within an a tag within an li within a ul. The menu is on the left hand-side, how do I open the videos on the same page in an iframe on the right hand side?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this is crashing Chrome in Stack Overflow when using the runnable code snippet, so here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redbmk/9Lqqnex7/). Assuming you have the layout already, you just need to create an iframe with the correct properties, then put it in the container you have on the right side of the page. Do this on a "click" event.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("open-video");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"),
        container = document.getElementById("frame-container");

    iframe.width = 420;
    iframe.height = 345;
    iframe.frameborder = 0;
    iframe.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?autoplay=1";

    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

```html
<button id="open-video">Click to play video</button>
<div id="frame-container"></div>
```